Problem use profile google Selenium python
I hope you're well, I've had a problem for 2 days, I'm trying to connect with Selenium to one of my google profiles but I can't; the aim is to fill in a Google Form automatically with Selenium but for this particular form you need to connect with your gmail account to be able to put the photos in.
Can someone help me connect to a Google profile with Selenium? I've been trying for 2 whole days without success:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os

# Chemin vers le profil utilisateur Chrome
user_profile_path = r"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data"

# Vérifie que le chemin existe
if not os.path.exists(user_profile_path):
    raise FileNotFoundError(f"Le chemin du profil Chrome n'existe pas : {user_profile_path}")

# Configuration de Chrome pour utiliser le profil existant
options = Options()
options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={user_profile_path}")  # Utiliser ton profil Chrome
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1")  # Utiliser un profil spécifique (par défaut "Default" ou "Profile 1")

# Ajout des options pour éviter les plantages
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")  # Désactive le sandbox
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")  # Pour résoudre des problèmes de mémoire
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")  # Pour ouvrir un port de débogage à distance

# Initialise le WebDriver avec les options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Ouvre la page Google
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/")

# Garde la fenêtre ouverte pour inspection
input("Appuyez sur Entrée pour quitter...")

# Ferme le navigateur
driver.quit()
   

